# Unique Meta Data for every webpage in the website

Tags: google-analytics, metadata

Below is my requirements.

Google Analytics had been implimented to the website and SEO'S have tried to edit the meta data on website for the required pages but  were not able to.

They demand a section to each page so the meta data entered is unique for every page. Currently every section on  pages are common and changes made on one will affect others.

I have a common header page that is included in every page of website, which is containing the meta data.

Kindly someone help regarding the exact php functionality that should be implimented for achieving the above requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the header in such a way that meta keywords are php variables and initialize variables to suitable values before the include in every pages .

OR

maintain a php assosciative array in header page. use the name of the page as the index and metakeywords of the page as values

then in header

```
<meta keywword='<?php echo $arrayname[basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], ".php");]?>'>
```

Comment: ;) i cant vote up with my current reputation ,@Vivek